# NexusIQ scan report

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nexus-iq

I'm dealing with some NexusIQ reports about `Highest Policy Threat` and `Security Violation Threat`
when upgrading to `org.springframework:spring-web@5.3.22` which is the version used under the `org.springframework.boot : spring-boot-starter-web : 2.7.3`.

Here is an image of the report for these dependencies;
[image]

It looks like apparently, even the latest version of the spring-web library has the same issue (See the picture). I have done some research and according to Snyk, the current version that I'm using has no direct vulnerabilities.
[image]

- Any idea which one is wrong?
- Am I interpreting these reports in the wrong way?
- How can I solve this issue in case the NexusIQ report is correct?

Answer (score 1):

This post has the full explanation of the dependency issue and the solution for it.

https://www.tenable.com/security/research/tra-2016-20